# Accessing GKE resources through kubectl (or client-go) after OAuth authentication to Google Cloud

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, oauth, google-iam

I have successfully completed an OAuth 2.0 flow to Google Cloud using the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform` scope.

I am now in possession of a token.

I want to be able to access kubernetes resources in GKE using `kubectl` or (preferably) through `client-go` library.

How can I use this token to

- get the credentials for a specific cluster that resides in a specific project?
- run something in the likes of creating / accessing a secret, e.g.

```
createdSecret, _ := clientset.CoreV1().Secrets(secret.Namespace).Create(ctx, secret, metav1.CreateOptions{})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer complements the one suggested by @DazWilkin

Assuming `token` is the `*oauth2.Token` [object](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/oauth2#Token) already retrieved via the `OAuth2.0` flow.
The dynamic in-memory kube config objects should be constructed as follows

```golang
 apiConfig := api.Config{
        APIVersion: "v1",
        Kind:       "Config",
        Clusters: map[string]*api.Cluster{
            clusterName: {
                CertificateAuthorityData: cert,
                Server:                   server,
            },
        },
        Contexts: map[string]*api.Context{
            clusterName: {
                Cluster:  clusterName,
                AuthInfo: clusterName,
            },
        },
        // CurrentContext: clusterName,
        AuthInfos: map[string]*api.AuthInfo{
            Token: token.AccessToken,
            clusterName: {
                AuthProvider: &api.AuthProviderConfig{
                    Name: "gcp",
                    Config: map[string]string{
                        "scopes": scopes,
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    }
```

Notice the addition of `Token: token.AccessToken,` in the `api.AuthInfo` struct.